# Is there a way in SQL server to interpret the underlying varchar(4) bits as an INT?

Tags: sql-server

I have data harvested from a binary file that has been encoded as a SQL column with type `varchar(4)`. This is not changeable. The 4 bytes used to create this varchar need to be interpreted sometimes as an `int` value (big endian). It would be nice if we could do this entirely inside SQL.

Printing the values in this `varchar(4)` column is not helpful as most of the bytes get interpreted as unprintable control characters.

I can't figure out how `CAST` or `CONVERT` can help since they seem to be tailored to converting a varchar like "0054" to int 54. Instead, I need the underlying bits to be interpreted as an int (big endian)--not the `varchar` characters as an `int`.

For example, one record prints this column as no visible characters, but `STRING_ESCAPE(@value,'json')`
will display
`\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007`

This needs to be interpreted somehow to be the int `7`

Here's a few more examples of what `STRING_ESCAPE` returns and what the int value should be:

```
\u0000\u0000\u0000\b     ==>  8
\u0000\u0000\u0000\t     ==>  9
\u0000\u0000\u0000\n     ==> 10
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000b ==> 11
\u0000\u0000\u0000\f     ==> 12
\u0000\u0000\u0000\r     ==> 13
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000e ==> 14
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000f ==> 15
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010 ==> 16
```

Thanks for your brain!

Comment: [`select cast(cast(crap_data as varbinary(4)) as int) from foo;`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3af58a2e3dadaabdcf751df66325a9ff)?

Comment: @GSerg Yes! thanks, I have to specify the size of the binary field. that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a table of sample data.  The first row represents your main example.  But you don't have any examples where any one of the first 3 characters is not character 0.  So I threw in another row where this is the case.

```
declare @values table (value char(4))
insert @values values 
    (char(0) + char(0) + char(0) + char(7)),
    (char(13) + char(9) + char(14) + char(8));
```

In the query below, I isolate each character using substring.  Then I call `ascii` to retrieve the character code.  What is not clear, however, is how you would take those integer values and combine them.  I give 3 possibilities.  'Option1' concatenates them.  'Option2' sums them together.  'Option3' concatenates them like option1, but pads them first so that there is a leading '0' if it is only one digit long.

```
select      escapedVal = string_escape(value,'json'),
            ap.*,
            option1 = convert(int,concat(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4)),
            option2 = pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4,
            option3 = convert(int,
                right('00' + convert(varchar(2),pos1),2) + 
                right('00' + convert(varchar(2),pos2),2) + 
                right('00' + convert(varchar(2),pos3),2) +  
                right('00' + convert(varchar(2),pos4),2)
            )
from        @values v
cross apply (select 
                pos1 = ascii(substring(value,1,1)),
                pos2 = ascii(substring(value,2,1)),
                pos3 = ascii(substring(value,3,1)),
                pos4 = ascii(substring(value,4,1))
            ) ap;
```

This produces:

| escapedVal | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | pos4 | option1 | option2 | option3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| \r\t\u000e\b | 13 | 9 | 14 | 8 | 139148 | 44 | 13091408 |

Comment: Thanks for you solution! I just found a shorter way. I found I needed to specify the size of binary or else it wouldn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(CAST(@value as BINARY(4)) as INT)
```

The part I was missing is specifying the size of binary as 4. Without the size, it always casts to 0!